# Jarnik's theorem in Falconer's book: what number?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, fractals

Simple reference question:

What is the theorem number/page number of *Jarnik's theorem* in Kenneth Falconer's Fractal Geometry (third ed.)?

Full reference:

> Falconer, Kenneth, 2014.
>
> **Fractal geometry: Mathematical foundations and applications.**
> Third edition. John Wiley & Sons, Ltd., Chichester.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.  If you have the book, why not just open it up to the index and look for the theorem?  If you do not have the book, of what use is the reference?

Comment: Here's why: it is for a citation, and lockdown separated me from the book.

Comment: I thought that would be clear?

Comment: No, it was not at all clear.  In any event, I don't have the third edition, but it is on page 155 of the second.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for my ambiguity in intention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference for 3rd Edition: Page 173, Theorem 10.3.